# rsync over ssh is not working anymore, while ssh itself is working fine (Write failed: broken pipe)

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-10.04, rsync, virtualbox

This issue started happening **after i changed router**. 
This is the scenario:

- Windows7 Host
- Ubuntu 10.04 Guest (VirtualBox)
- Ubuntu 10.04 remote server

What i used to do is run a very basic rsync command:

```
rsync -avz --delete /local/path/ username@host:/path/to/remote/directory
```

This worked perfect until i did change adsl provider, and i changed router aswell: now, this happens:

- rsync on Ubuntu Guest is not working anymore (to any random server), if using this **new** router
- rsync on Ubuntu Guest is WORKING, if i switch back to **old** router
- i tried a new virtual box ubuntu install, and the command is WORKING
  with both the routers

So, the not-working-combo is oldUbuntu + newRouter.

To get things worst, i can state that (on the not-working ubuntu)

- i ping the remote host
- plain ssh connection to the remote host is working fine (i can auth, connect, and do stuff on the remote host)
- scp is NOT working (this is just a further thing i tried)

This is the console output of the execution, with ssh verbose set to vvvv:

```
root@client:~# rsync -ae 'ssh -vvvv' /root/test-rsync/ {username}@{hostname}:/home/{username}/test/
OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for {hostname}
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to {hostname} [{ip.add.re.ss}] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /root/.ssh/{private_key}.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/{private_key} type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: Wrote 792 bytes for a total of 831
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 zlib@openssh.com
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 zlib@openssh.com
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug3: Wrote 24 bytes for a total of 855
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 125/256
debug2: bits set: 525/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug3: Wrote 144 bytes for a total of 999
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /root/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 4
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /root/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 5
debug1: Host '{hostname}' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug2: bits set: 512/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: Wrote 16 bytes for a total of 1015
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug3: Wrote 48 bytes for a total of 1063
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/{private_key} (0x7f3ad0e7f9b0)
debug3: Wrote 80 bytes for a total of 1143
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,gssapi,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/{private_key}
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 368 bytes for a total of 1511
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp 1b:65:36:92:59:b3:12:3e:8c:c6:03:28:d4:81:09:dc
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug3: Wrote 656 bytes for a total of 2167
debug1: Enabling compression at level 6.
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug3: Wrote 112 bytes for a total of 2279
debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CLIENT
debug3: Ignored env SSH_TTY
debug1: Sending env LC_ALL = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env LANGUAGE
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CONNECTION
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE
debug3: Ignored env _
debug1: Sending command: rsync --server -logDtpre.iLsf . /home/{username}/test/
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: Wrote 208 bytes for a total of 2487
```

At this point everything freeze for lots of minutes, ending in

```
Write failed: Broken pipe
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(601) [sender=3.0.7]
```

Any suggestion?

Thank You

F.

*Edit 2012/09/13: i am changing title and issue definition, since i made some TINY step ahead and i think i can give more detailed clues.*

Comment: Can you do a simple command (like whoami) remotely via ssh with the -vvvv option to cross compare? "ssh -vvvv youruser@remotehost whoami". I am concerned about the key errors.

Comment: Continuing Skaperen's line: can you provide the output of:  "ssh username@host true" (replace your username and hostname).  It shouldn't have _any_ output.  If it does, this is the problem that confuses rsync. Note the "0 bytes received so far" from rsync when it gives up.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may have a packet fragmentation issue. This issue can also manifest itself when browsing and connections to sites suddenly timing out. SSH itself works fine because its packets are quite small, but once you do a relatively large file transfer, packets may get dropped.

A tcpdump may give you a clue if that is the case.

You can try lowering the MTU on your non working desktop and see if that fixes the problem. The default is 1500, try putting it down to 1200 or so. Or just follow [this advice](http://www.snailbook.com/faq/mtu-mismatch.auto.html) which says pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the remote shell command using -e option and see if that helps.
Eg:

```
$ rsync -avz --delete /path/to/source -e "ssh -i /path/to/key" username@hostname.com:/path/to/destination
```

Comment: Tried your soulution mate, this is not working. I insist, this is nothing about ssh. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

New router may not have DNS server IPs set up to valid DNS cache servers it can reach, plus default sshd config set to disallow from unknown clients.

Comment: Hello, i was thinking about DNS too. What am i supposed to do to solve this? Furthermore, why are both PING and plain SSH working then?

Comment: This cannot possibly be a DNS issue.  Based on the error message, rsync detects a data error after DNS works fine, the connection is established, and the rsync command itself makes it through the connection.